# Firefox doesn't render FontAwesome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, font-awesome

for some odd reason Firefox doesn't render FontAwesome properly. It works in Chrome and in Safari, just not in Firefox.

Font Awesome was added via Bower and therefore loaded locally. Nothing via CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css">
```

This is how it looks in Firefox (wrong):

[image: Firefox]

This is how it looks in Chrome & Safari (correct):

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Tried to load it via CDN and added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to
  .htaccess
- Moved fonts into same directory (to check if it was a relative path
  problem)

Nothing worked up until now.

/// EDIT

This is how its shown in the Inspector
[image]

Comment: I dont think it's a Firefox issue.  Try loading your fonts directly from `//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: Is this page loading from http or from a file system?

Comment: loaded from file system

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've had problems loading things at certain times from a file:// url in firefox.  Could you try to reproduce from a web server?

Comment: @Tino have you seen [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/446001/firefox-cannot-render-icons-from-font-awesome-webfont-set)?

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the problem. I was under the impression that it wouldn't matter at which position I would load the Font Awesome css file. It was one of the first css files loaded in the header. I moved it to the last position and now it works just fine.

I couldn't find out why exactly this fixes the problem in firefox, but it did the trick. What I still find extremely strange is, that it matters the order in which the css is loaded in firefox, but not in chrome and safari.

Maybe someone else knows more about this.

Comment: I have been wondering if order matters when it comes to markup, font files, and css files. It seems like it could be an issue with IE especially.  Have you learned anything else about this?